# how to Add Apache License 2.0 in an Android App which is using a library powered by Apache

Tags: android, apache, licensing

I need my app to use a library project which is powered by Apache, i'm only liable to use that library if i add  [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) 
in my app. 
My question is that where to add the license in the app?

Is it okay, if i add the boilerplate notice only in the About Section of the app.

**Boilerplate notice:**

> Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
>   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
>   You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
>   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
>   limitations under the License.

Comment: As an example, if you look at the Google Play application, the open source licenses are listed in _Settings_ under the title _About_. So, yes. Adding the license in the _About Section_ of your app should be good enough.

Comment: thanks @IceMAN for the response, could you please clarify more that is it okay to use only boilerplate notice or to state the whole Apache License 2.0.

Comment: I would go with the entire license. If the library requires the entire license then play safe and post it in it's entirety.

Comment: Ok, Thanks alot for your valuable help :) @IceMAN

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about legal advice, not programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - not relevant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *OSS Licenses Gradle Plugin* to your app. This Gradle plugin scans the POM dependencies of a project at compile time. When a Maven POM exists for a direct dependency of the app, the plugin processes the  element and embeds the link and title of each license in an Android asset in the final app APK.

Refer the following link for details:
https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/oss-licenses-plugin